# NSIS XML updation (Wizou's plugin) query

Tags: nsis

I'm trying to read a node value from an xml file and store it in a variable to put it back into another xml file. I'm doing this inside an NSIS installer using NSIS XML plugin (By Wizou), the problem i'm facing is its not reading the node value, the code i'm using is below,

```
nsisXML::create
nsisXML::load '${CONFIG}' /* This is the XML file for reading the value*/
messagebox MB_OK "Value in var0 is $0"
nsisXML::select '/hibernate-configuration/session-factory/property[@name="connection.connection_string"]'
messagebox MB_OK "Value in var1 is $1"
messagebox MB_OK "Value in var2 is $2"
```

After the initial load of the file(File exists in the referred path), i'm getting some value in $0 which means xml file is getting loaded, after which i'm trying to select the node from where it reads the value. But after the nsisxml::select statement the var's $1 and $2 has value 0 which suggests it can't find the node, but its there in the xml when you look at it, the XML file contents are below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
<session-factory>
<property name="connection.provider">
NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
</property>
<property name="dialect">
NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect
</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">
NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver
</property>
<property name="connection.connection_string">
DB String 
</property>
<property name="query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</property>
<property name="cache.provider_class">NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.SysCacheProvider, NHibernate.Caches.SysCache</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Any idea where i could be going wrong with this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your XPath search string does not deal with the xmlns.

You can ignore the xmlns like this:

```
InitPluginsDir
FileOpen $0 "$pluginsdir\Test.xml" w
FileWrite $0 '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>$\r$\n'
FileWrite $0 '<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">$\r$\n'
FileWrite $0 '<session-factory>$\r$\n'
FileWrite $0 '<property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>$\r$\n'
FileWrite $0 '<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>$\r$\n'
FileWrite $0 '<property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>$\r$\n'
FileWrite $0 '<property name="connection.connection_string">DB String</property>$\r$\n'
FileWrite $0 `<property name="query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</property>$\r$\n`
FileWrite $0 '<property name="cache.provider_class">NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.SysCacheProvider, NHibernate.Caches.SysCache</property>$\r$\n'
FileWrite $0 '</session-factory>$\r$\n'
FileWrite $0 '</hibernate-configuration>$\r$\n'
FileClose $0

nsisXML::create
nsisXML::load "$pluginsdir\Test.xml"
DetailPrint doc=$0
nsisXML::select `/*[name()='hibernate-configuration']/*[name()='session-factory']/*[name()='property'][@name="connection.connection_string"]`
DetailPrint 1=$1,2=$2,3=$3
```

Comment: hey, thank you for clearing that up...actually i went with the next available XML plugin available for NSIS, now kind of stuck with that...about to open another post for that..